# Receive Push Notification in Windows with delphi application?

Tags: windows, delphi, uwp, push, wns

I would like to create a Windows application in Delphi 10 enabled to receive push notifications.

I have seen that in Delphi 10 there is the BaaS provider to which to hook services like Kinvey, Parse, EMS. But I found serious problems, too many to summarize them here.
I have seen that Windows 10 can receive push notifications like in the Pushsafer client. In this case it is a question of developing a UWP App.
Delphi 10 (Tokyo) allows you to create a UWP App but it's a dark world for me.
I have looked for examples by sea and by mountains but it seems that it is not a very treated subject.
The question then is how to create a UWP App in Delphi enabled to receive Push notifications from Pushsafer or WNS?

Comment: You never know!